# What is the correct approach to check if array exists in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm getting the below error when I check the length of an array. What would be the correct approach?

main.js

```
if (drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage.length !== 0 && Array.isArray(drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage)) {
   //code goes here 
}
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: Remove the length check. Done.

Comment: swap your checks ... if( isArray && arr.length ) ... the code executes in the order that it is read.  if there is no array, there is no length, thus the error.

Comment: An array can exist if the length === 0 as well

Comment: sometime i get empty array so i need to check length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try swapping the order of the checks:

```
if (Array.isArray(drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage) && drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage.length !== 0) {
                                        code goes here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Validate your data, swapping the condition may help but it won't prevent, some errors from happeing. For example `Array.isArray(drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage)` will throw an error if `drugPrice.mailPrice` is undefined.

```
if (drugPrice.mailPrice 
    && drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage 
    && drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage.length !== 0 
    && Array.isArray(drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage)) {
  // code goes here 
}
```

```js
var drugPrice = { mailPrice: { rejectMessage: {} } };

if (drugPrice.mailPrice 
    && drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage 
    && drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage.length !== 0 
    && Array.isArray(drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage)) {

  console.log('success');
} else {
  console.log('fail')
}
```

**NOTE**

Always validate your data. Don't assume that you'll always get the right data. When working with objects always validate them, as doing `data.name`, can break your app, if `data` is null or undefined. for example, given the following object.

```
const drugPrice = { mailPrice: null };
```

doing, throws an error.

```js
const drugPrice = { mailPrice: null };

// throws an error, Cannot read property 'rejectMessage' of undefined
if (Array.isArray(drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage)) {
}
```

to prevent that from happening, we need to check if the propery exists, like the following.

```js
const drugPrice = { mailPrice: null };
console.log(drugPrice.mailPrice && Array.isArray(drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage) || 'Price is null or undefined')
```

Comment: While you're making valid points, this misses the actual problem in the original code, and is therefore incorrect.  Try -> `var drugPrice = { mailPrice: { rejectMessage: {} } };`

Comment: maybe I'm missing something https://jsbin.com/xabuwibavu/edit?js,console

Comment: Actually, sorry - I take it back.  I don't understand why that code doesn't throw an error at `rejectMessage.length` if `rejectMessage` is something other than an array (or string).

Comment: it doesn't throw an because `rejectMessage` exists and it's an object.

Comment: It's assumption on my part, probably formed out of my habit of *always* putting `.isArray()` before a length check.  I apologise.  If edit your answer I can remove my incorrect downvote.

Comment: It's ok, I validate objects before i do anything with them.

Comment: Of course.  We just do it differently and it threw me :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to actually do the `.length !== 0`. You can simply do:

```
if (Array.isArray(A.B.C) && A.B.C.length) {  // <-- order is important here
    //...
}
```

`.length` would be evaluated as a boolean and it will give you the same result as checking with `!==0`

That being said however your paths are quite long so you probably would want to make sure they are valid. Meaning if `drugPrice` or `mailPrice` are falsey you would have an issue. So usually you would want to check on them as well. Since your question was about the array part I will skip those but just as FYI.

You can build your own path checker or if you use libraries like lodash/underscore etc they always have a handy `get/has` functions to check like this (with `lodash`):

```
if (_.has(drugPrice, 'mailPrice.rejectMessage.length'))
    //...
}
```

Obviously do not use those libraries just for that but if you already have them those methods are quite handy. You can simply check each of the paths as well via:

```
if (A && A.B && Array.isArray(A.B.C) && A.B.C.length) {
    //...
}
```

It just gets tedious if you have long object paths etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that javascript checks array length before checking if the array is the type of the array. You should change the order in the if statement.

You can try with:

```
if (myArr && Array.isArray(myArr) && myArr.length !== 0) {
    // your code
}
```

Now the code is executed in the right order.

1. The first condition checks if myArr is defined,
2. The second condition checks if myArr is the type of Array, you can also do this way:

   if (myArr && myArr.push && myArr.length !== 0) {
        // your code
   }
3. The third condition checks if myArr is not empty.